# Why does the second variable not change in the field?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list, comma-operator

I'm testing some programms for my lectures. I'm creating classes and use a paramterlist to initalize a field but the second variable doesn't change.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Punkt {

    int x;
    int y;

public:
    Punkt(int a = 0, int b = 0)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;

    }
    void printXY()
    {
        cout << "x= " << x << " y= " << y << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    Punkt pFeld[] = { (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3) };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pFeld[i].printXY();
    cin.get();
};
```

No error messages. Expected result was that x and y change, while actual result is that only x changes and y stays 0.

Comment: `Punkt pFeld[] = { {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3} };`

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings, for example, on gcc [I get the following message](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uYunmJ7votz706G5): `warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
  Punkt pFeld[] = { (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3) };`

Comment: `(1,1)` is an expression that gives a result of `1`, not a representation of a pair of vaues.  So the constructor of `Punkt` is being passed a single value for the argument `a`, and default value (`0`) for the argument `b`.   Use `{}` instead of `()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
(1, 1)
```

is an expression with the comma operator.

In fact this initialization

```
Punkt pFeld[] = { (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3) };
```

is equivalent to

```
Punkt pFeld[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

So the constructor with the second default argument equal to 0 is called three times.

Use instead

```
{ 1, 1 }
```

Here is your updated code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Punkt {

    int x;
    int y;

public:
    Punkt(int a = 0, int b = 0)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;

    }
    void printXY()
    {
        cout << "x= " << x << " y= " << y << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    Punkt pFeld[] = { {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3} };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pFeld[i].printXY();
    cin.get();
}
```

Its output is

```
x= 1 y= 1
x= 2 y= 2
x= 3 y= 3
```

Pay attention to that the semicolon after the function main is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Passing `(1, 1)` to the constructor of `Punkt`, the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) will return the 2nd operand as the result (the 1st operand is discarded), so you're only passing one `int` with value `1` to the constructor. That's why `y` is always initialized as `0`.

What you want should be

```
Punkt pFeld[] = { {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3} }; // list initialization since C++11
```

or

```
Punkt pFeld[] = { Punkt(1, 1), Punkt(2, 2), Punkt(3, 3) };
```